# How to make a conditional request with NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I'm new to `NSManagedObjectContext`. I have created an entity `Link` in my app, which contains a `NSString *url`.

At some point of my app, I need to insert a new `Link` in my base, so I simply do this :

```
Link *link = [NSEntityDescription 
                         insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Link" 
                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
link.url = myUrl;
```

But before doing this, I want to check if there is not already a Link in my base with the same url. And I have no idea of how to do so... what should I do?

**EDIT** : to retrieve data from the base I'm using this method from a tool I found on the web:

```
// Fetch objects with a predicate
+(NSMutableArray *)searchObjectsForEntity:(NSString*)entityName withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate andSortKey:(NSString*)sortKey andSortAscending:(BOOL)sortAscending andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    // Create fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // If a predicate was specified then use it in the request
    if (predicate != nil)
        [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // If a sort key was passed then use it in the request
    if (sortKey != nil) {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:sortAscending];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }

    // Execute the fetch request
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    // If the returned array was nil then there was an error
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil)
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get objects for entity %@", entityName);

    // Return the results
    return mutableFetchResults;
}
```

I would like to know how to use it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you provided just searches for a NSManagedObject that matches the attributes in the NSManagedObjectContext and if one exists, it returns it.

But, what you need to implement is called the Find-or-Create pattern, which is discussed in the Core Data programming guide. Basically, you search for an object matching specific criteria and if it exists that object is returned. If that object does not exist you create it.

[Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4)

E.g.

```
+ (NSString *)entityName
{
    return NSStringFromClass([Link class]);
}

+ (instancetype)findUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Link * entity;

    // Setup the fetchRequest
    NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[[self class] entityName]];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

    // Credit: @Martin R
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];

    // Execute the fetchRequest
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray * matchingLinks = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    // MatchingLinks will only return nil if an error has occurred otherwise it will return 0
    if (!matchingLinks)
    {
        // handle error
        // Core data returns nil if an error occured
        NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [error description]);
    }
    else if ([matchingLinks count] <= 0)
    {
        // if the count <= 0, there were no matches

        NSLog(@"%s Not found", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    } else {

        // A link with a url that matches the url in the dictionary was found.
        NSLog(@"%s Found", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        entity = [matchingLinks lastObject];
    }

    return entity;
}

+ (instancetype)findUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate orCreateWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Link * entity = [[self class] findUsingPredicate:predicate withContext:context];

    if (!entity) {
        entity = [[self class] createWithContext:context];
    }

    return entity;
}

+ (isntancetype)createWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return [[self class] alloc] initWithContext:context];
}

- (instancetype)initWithContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Link * entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[[self class] entityName] inManagedObjectContext:context];

    return entity;
}
```

**USE CASE:**

```
NSString * url = @"http://www.mylink.com";
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url = %@", url];
Link * link = [Link findUsingPredicate:predicate orCreateWithContext:self.managedObjectContext];
link.url = url;
```

Comment: Possible improvements: The sort descriptor is not needed. The fetch limit can be set to 1. - And why call the `description` method when creating the predicate? That is either not necessary or error-prone.

Comment: @Martin R, Technically you're right. The description method when creating the predicate is not necessary, but my thought was if the url is a string then why not go ahead and get the textual representation of it.

Comment: Using `description` to forcefully convert "something" to a string often hides problems. I have seen some questions where the real problem was that a dictionary/managed object/something was converted to a string using description, and the people asked "How can I convert this back" or "How to remove the quotation marks in this string" ...

Comment: @Martin R, Well, I have removed the description method from the predicate. I haven't had problems using description, but I guess I should research it more. As for the sortDescriptor though, atleast one must be provided, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No, a fetch request does not require a sort descriptor. Since you are only interested in the existence of at least one matching object, it is not needed.

Comment: @Martin R, Oh, I had no idea. Makes sense when you think about. Thank you for teaching me something new.

Comment: ["Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" is the link you are looking for :-)

Comment: @Martin R, Thank you so much! It would have bugged me until I found out what the name of that pattern was.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (with your method):

```
AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = del.managedObjectContext;
NSString *urlString = @"YOUR URL HERE";

NSMutableArray *fetchedResults =  [self  searchObjectsForEntity:@"Link" withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url == %@", urlString] andSortKey:@"url" andSortAscending:YES andContext:managedObjectContext];

BOOL exist = NO;

if(fetchedResults.count >= 1){
    exist = YES;
}
```